# Segue show is working on iPhone 5 & 6 but not on the iPhone 4 simulator

Tags: swift

After I embedded a navigation controller, my "action segue show" will successfully transition back to the home page on my iPhone 5 and 6 stimulator. But on the iPhone 4 and iPad stimulator there is no transition

Comment: Always the same iOS version?

Comment: I just deleted the button and made a new one which seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Then answer you question yourself to help people with the same problem.